# React-Router subroutes not displaying

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router

It seems that when webpack builds the file the output can only see the maincard div and none of the contents therein.  I'm not sure what's missing as when this is run as npm react-scripts start it works fine.  I'm not sure what i'm missing from webpack for this to render correctly.  I'm trying to load this into an S3 bucket so it has to be packed with the webpack.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Route, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import { fetchUserList } from "../actions/UserActions";
import { fetchSkillList } from "../actions/SkillActions";

import WelcomeCard from "./WelcomeCard";
import UserSearchCard from "./UserSearchCard";
import AddUserCard from './AddUserCard';

import '../styles/MainCard.css';

class MainCard extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchUserList();
        this.props.fetchSkillList();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="main_card">
                <Route exact path='/' component={WelcomeCard}/>
                <Route path='/list' component={UserSearchCard}/>
                <Route path='/new' component={AddUserCard}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        fetchUserList: () => dispatch(fetchUserList()),
        fetchSkillList: () => dispatch(fetchSkillList())
    }
};

export default withRouter( connect(undefined, mapDispatchToProps)(MainCard) );
```

Webpack Config:

```
let path = require('path');
let webpack = require('webpack');
const publicPath = '/dist/build/';
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')

module.exports = {
    //Content
    entry: './src/index.js',
    mode: 'development',
    // A SourceMap without column-mappings ignoring loaded Source Maps.
    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
            }
        }),
        //simplifies creation of HTML files to serve your webpack bundles. This is especially useful for webpack bundles that include a hash in the filename which changes every compilation. You can either let the plugin generate an HTML file for you, supply your own template using lodash templates or use your own loader.
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Talent Identification Manager'
        }),
        //Auto replacement of page when i save some file, even css
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "[name].css",
            chunkFilename: "[id].css"
        })
    ],

    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, publicPath),
        filename: 'main.bundle-0.0.1.js',
        publicPath: "/",
        sourceMapFilename: 'main.map',
    },

    devServer: {
        port: 3000,
        host: 'localhost',
        //Be possible go back pressing the "back" button at chrome
        historyApiFallback: true,
        noInfo: false,
        stats: 'minimal',
        publicPath: publicPath,
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, publicPath),
        //hotmodulereplacementeplugin
        hot: true
    },
    module: {

        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules(?!\/webpack-dev-server)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-2'],
                    plugins: ['syntax-decorators']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    'file-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the URL of your live site?

Comment: https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/talentidbucket/index.html

Comment: Great. React Router doesn't know that you want to treat `/talentidbucket` as the base of your site, so you have to pass it as the `basename` prop to the `BrowserRouter` in production. `<BrowserRouter basename="/talentidbucket" > {/* ... */} </BrowserRouter>`

Comment: This was exactly the problem.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React Router doesn't know that you want to treat `/talentidbucket` as the base of your site, so you have explicitly tell it so by passing the base path as the `basename` prop of the `BrowserRouter` component in production.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter basename="/talentidbucket"> {/* ... */} </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```